# import "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" in activity_main.xml file

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i want to learn swipe technology to change my pages from a tutorial. in that tutorial, he used "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" in main xml  file. but i dont know where must i attach  this code in my file in android studio environment.my main problem is when i attached "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" in every place in my xml code, it indicate an error and i dont know where is the right place to attach it.  this is my  main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout

    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  // error  is here
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and error in gradle is :

```
Error:(3) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\iman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: What does your error say, specifically? Paste from LogCat.

Comment: i edited my question with added error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Check out this gist I created for you
https://gist.github.com/akodiakson/7e77790317d86e7a6bee

The problem is that `RelativeLayout` wasn't closed. Your `ViewPager` needs to be declared within the `RelativeLayout`.

--

In your `build.gradle`, you'll need to add the v4 Support Library

`compile com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1` //or whatever version you need or have

In another layout file, you'll need to declare a ViewPager layout.

`<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ... ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>`

Comment: how can i add v4 support library in android studio ??

Comment: See the above answer, the `compile com.android....` line will tell gradle to get that dependency.

Comment: i think i have support library ... my sdk indicate  "installed" ... and i think i dont know right place to use "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" in xml file.

Comment: See the updated answer. You might want to read up on some Android layout basics and working with XML.

Comment: great. how can i learn xml in android? do you know a good reference ??

Answer (score 2):

Edit as below you missed "<" android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

```
<RelativeLayout

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  // error  is here
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```